# Ubuntu and w10 can't boot after installing second hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I have a lenovo laptop(g505s), I installed an SSD and removed the CD player to install a tray with the hard disk which used to work fine. I had Windows 10 in the SSD and I used the hard disk only for data.

Yesterday, I decided to install Ubuntu 14.04 in the SSD (now the SSD has both operating systems). The problem is that neither Windows 10 nor Ubuntu can boot (black screen) when I have the hard disk in the tray. Both operating systems boot normally when I remove the hdd.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your boot priority is not set correct. Go into BIOS and change the SSD or Ubuntu boot loader (newer bios versions might say that). to option #1.

Comment: i tried it in bios, still remain the problem.